# `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` fails with a `no file received` error

Tags: android, kotlin

#### My current code :

Just focus on the `fileOpener` variable. The `SafeFiles` class is a self declared variable which has the file's extensions and such. Don't worry too much about it.

```
fileOpener = { file: File ->
    val uri: Uri = Uri.fromFile(file).normalizeScheme()
    val mime = MimeTypeMap
        .getSingleton()
        .getMimeTypeFromExtension(safeFile.extension.substring(1))
    Log.d(TAG, "mime = $mime")
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.data = uri
    intent.type = mime
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    Log.d(
        TAG, "data received:" +
                "uri = $uri\n" +
                "extension = ${safeFile.extension.substring(1)}\n" +
                "path = ${file.absolutePath}\n" +
                "size = ${file.totalSpace} "
    )
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        context!!.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

#### Logs -

```
2022-07-30 16:41:41.005 19233-19285/com.example.cryptile D/SafeViewerFragment: mime = image/png
2022-07-30 16:41:41.005 19233-19285/com.example.cryptile D/SafeViewerFragment: data received:uri = file:///storage/emulated/0/Cryptile/CRYPTILE_2022_07_30/.CACHE/aa854c7e-9fa4-4313-9750-cf58fde467b8.png
    extension = png
    path = /storage/emulated/0/Cryptile/CRYPTILE_2022_07_30/.CACHE/aa854c7e-9fa4-4313-9750-cf58fde467b8.png
    size = 119640424448
```

Clearly, the size not being zero means the file exists. I have also opened the mentioned file from the device's file explorer and everything seems to work fine. the only conclusion I came to is this might be some issue with the file provider. So, here's the manifest -

#### Manifest -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cryptile">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />

    <application
        android:name=".app_data.AppApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CRYPTILE">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.cryptile.fileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

#### And the filepaths.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="/storage/emulated/0"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this might have helped -

```
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
```

My final code is -

```
fileOpener = { file: File ->
    val uri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        requireContext(),
        "com.example.cryptile.fileProvider",
        file
    )
    val mime = MimeTypeMap
        .getSingleton()
        .getMimeTypeFromExtension(safeFile.extension.substring(1))
    Log.d(TAG, "mime = $mime")

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime)
    Log.d(
        TAG, "data received:" +
                "uri = $uri\n" +
                "extension = ${safeFile.extension.substring(1)}\n" +
                "path = ${file.absolutePath}\n" +
                "size = ${file.totalSpace} "
    )
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        context!!.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Didn't make any changes anywhere else outside this lambda. Just make sure to compare the intent code because it is a little different compared to the question's code.

Answer (score 1):

> the only conclusion I came to is this might be some issue with the file provider

You are not using `FileProvider`. You are using `Uri.fromFile()`, which has been all but banned for six years.

Replace:

```kotlin
val uri: Uri = Uri.fromFile(file).normalizeScheme()
```

with:

```kotlin
val uri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context!!, "com.example.cryptile.fileProvider", file)
```

(and then rewrite your code to avoid the `!!`)